# dynamic span class within a php file.

Tags: php, css, class, html

not really a php guy, but have a question. I'm wanting to take the following statement

```
    $_POST['subject'] =  $_POST['post_prefix'] . '  ' . $_POST['subject'];
```

I would like the

```
$_POST['post_prefix']
```

part to be within a span class so I can add some css styling to it.

So it ends up as something like

```
<span class="$_POST['post_prefix']">$_POST['post_prefix']</span>
```

I tried a few methods on here via search, but phpstorm keeps giving me errors all over the place about semicolons. So thought I'd ask the pros to save my sanity.

If there's a better way of doing this, then that would also be helpful.

Cheers.

Comment: You also shouldn't set $_POST variables yourself like you are doing with $_POST['subject'].  You should let the page do that itself and should be setting to a $_SESSION: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3235265/1744357

Comment: Hi Veer, $_POST is used by Simple Machines Forum for numerous reasons. I was editing the Post.php file within this to manipulate how the subject line of a topic is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that will give you errors, for sure, actually, `$_POST['variable_name']` means something to `PHP` but not to `HTML`.

`PHP` creates a `HTML` page using its own variable. here `$_POST['variable_name']` is a `PHP` variable so you need to print that variable in `HTML`

So, use this,

```
<span class="<?php echo $_POST['post_prefix'] ?>"><?php echo $_POST['post_prefix'] ?></span>
```

Here you are printing the `PHP` variable to make a mock `HTML`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<span class="<?php echo $_POST['post_prefix'] ?>"><?php echo $_POST['post_prefix'] ?></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<span class="<?php echo $_POST['post_prefix']; ?>"><?php echo $_POST['post_prefix']; ?></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work exactly

```
 $_POST['subject'] =  '<span class='.$_POST['post_prefix'].'>'.$_POST['post_prefix'].'</span>' . '  ' . $_POST['subject'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a PHP file, with no HTML flowing around, try

```
echo "<span class='".$_POST['post_prefix']."'>".$_POST['post_prefix']."</span>";
```